# Spivak's Calculus Chapter 11 Problem 50 : does g''(x) exist?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The problem is as follows:

> Define $f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{x}$ if $x \neq 0$ and $f(x) = 0$ if $x = 0.$ Also, $g(0) = g'(0) = 0$, and $g''(0) = 17$. Find $f'(0).$

I tried the following method: We want to find $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}$ by using L'hopital's rule. We have that 
$$f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{g(x)}{x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{g'(x)}{2x}.$$

I am stuck at how to prove $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{g'(x)}{2x}$ using L'hopital's Theorem, as one of the conditions to apply the theorem requires $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{g''(x)}{2}$ to exist; **however, how do we know that $g''(x)$ exists?** I have actually solved this problem by doing $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{g'(x)}{2x} = \frac{1}{2} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{g'(x)}{x} = \frac{g''(0)}{2} = \frac{17}{2}.$$

But I would really be interested in how to apply L'Hopital's a second time. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You have 
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{g'(x)}{x} = g''(0)
$$
by definition of the derivative (of $g'$).

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers here adress your concern. The simple answer is that we don't know that $g''(x)$ exists. We only know that $g''(0)$ exists (and from that implicitely that $g'$ exists in a neighborhood of $0$, so we can make sense of the limit).

Thus, you can't use l'Hopital's rule in the way you tried.